# How to debug a HoloLens2 app? Unity, MRTK, Ros2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am building app with https://github.com/ms-iot/ros_msft_mrtk with Unity for the Hololens2.
To test the communication I want to get debug output.

I tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/managed-debugging-with-unity-il2cpp
To test the output, I tried these methods:
`Debug.Log("Try"); Console.WriteLine("Try"); System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Try");`

I selected the conditions, set the build settings, connected Hololens via WIFI, opened the script where the debug output methods are and attached Unity debugger.

Maybe I'm not selecting the right device? When I attach Unity debugger, I can select from type "Editor" and "Editor (background)".

Also, I get the debug output "The data area passed to a system call is too small."

But I don't get any of my debug output. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the solution has not been deployed to HoleLens. If the release platform is set in Unity, build gets the corresponding solution and deploys the solution to HoloLens through VS.

1. On the debug toolbar, set the Debug option to Release , and set the ARM to X86 , and select Device for the run item.
2. Connect the HoloLens to the host via USB or WIFI. When deploying for the first time, you need to open the http://127.0.0.1:10080 interface for user configuration.
   At this point, there will be a PIN code for the device connection in VS. Enter the PIN code that appears in the developer mode of the HoloLens to complete the device pairing.
3. On the menu bar, click Debug->Start Execution (without debugging) If the configuration is normal, VS will deploy the solution generated by build to HoloLens at this time.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't the Hololens2 require ARM?
And the app is built and run on the Hololens2. I had already connected it. Only debugging does not work.

Comment: Correct, HoloLens 2 would be ARM.  The Debug.Log() calls will not show up inside of Visual Studio but would if Unity is used in debugging.  One tactic a developer uses often is to log the debug out to screen into a text field if a debugger cannot be attached.